# How to refer to a function that will be declared after script loading

Tags: javascript, dom-events, gigya

In a Sitecore environment, where I CANNOT reorder the js scripts instantiated at the end of the `<body>`, I need to check if one of the function (**Gigya**) in those scripts has returned a true value (*I need to check if a user is logged in or not*).

My script can be loaded ONLY **before** those scripts are loaded, so my script checks if a given function has a true return value before that said function has to be called.

Given the structure situation, what I always get is an error of unknown function.

Is there a way to bypass this? I mean, I have tried to attach at the body an ad-hoc script containing my check-function at the end of the loading process, but with no success.

Any hint? Maybe adding listeners?

Comment: is the function a promise ?

Comment: @DhananjaiPai my function or the one I need to check? In the first case, no, it's not. In the second case, code is compiled, so I cannot read it properly.

Comment: How are you adding the Gigya code into the page? is it using <script> tags ?

Comment: @DhananjaiPai Yes, it is added at the end of the body.

Answer (score 1):

**Approach 1**

Since the function you need to wait for is loaded with `<script>` tags you could wrap your entire code inside a function and call that function with onload

`<script src="...gigya..." onload="functionToExecute()">`

**Approach 2**

instead of calling the `functionToExecute` you could create a new synthetic event, say "gigyaloaded" and listen to it before your functions are called.

[ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events ]

the event should be emitted with script onload like above.

Comment: Thank you. I will give it a try in a few moments.

Comment: It looks like I cannot add onload="anyFunction()" to the script declaration, because all the scripts are loaded by an automation of Sitecore, that attaches scripts as resources. They're telling me that there is no way to add onload="" in the script declaration. As per Approach 2, I am try to figure out your method, but I would really need some more hints. Can you help me? The functions I call are: 
gigya.socialize.getUserInfo({ callback: renderUI });
  gigya.socialize.addEventHandlers({ onConnectionAdded: renderUI, onConnectionRemoved: renderUI });
What should be the logic?